# Android force close when using setBackgroundColor and setImageDrawable in loop

Tags: android, image, imageview

I want to set background color of a dynamically created view but I **got force close at:**

```
item1.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.black);
```

in below code :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        View shelfRow;
        shelfRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shelf_row2);
        ImageView item1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.row_item1);
        item1.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.black);
        parentPanel.addView(shelfRow);
    }
```

and also using **setImageDrawable** to set drawable **got same result.**

Comment: Post the stack trace if this is not the case, but I'm pretty sure your problem is that item is null.

Comment: You can't apply TextColor for ImageView, but you can set Background Image for that Image View

Comment: ADR you can put Color for a ImageView Backgrund or SRC.
We need the stacktrace to answer this question. 99% item1 is null because findViewById return null. Is a listView or something similar?

Comment: Just for knowledge. When getting color from resource you need to use the function [Resource.getColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)), you can not use the ID as color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create imageview dynamically.

```
ImageView images[];
     View shelfRow[] =new View[numberOfRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        images = new ImageView[numberOfRows];

        shelfRow[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shelf_row2);
        images[i].setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.black);
        parentPanel.addView(shelfRow[i]);
    }
```

Or create 10 imageviews and give id to it like..

```
int[] buttonIDs = new int[] {R.id.button1ID, R.id.button2ID, R.id.button3ID, ... };
              View shelfRow[] =new View[numberOfRows];
    ImageView[] forAdapter = new ImageView[numberOfRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        forAdapter[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(buttonIDs[i]);

        shelfRow[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shelf_row2);
        forAdapter[i].setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.black);
        parentPanel.addView(shelfRow[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
View shelfRow;
shelfRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shelf_row2);
```

Please note that,  View shelfRow, havent been initialized yet, so its value is null.
you are invoking setBackgroundResource() method on a null object, first initialize shelfRow, with some value and then invoke a method on the object.